# can you solve this ? $ y'= \frac{x\sqrt{1+y^2}} { y\sqrt{1+x^2}} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

thanks, hard to write with keyboard
$$
y'= \frac{x\sqrt{1+y^2}} { y\sqrt{1+x^2}}  
$$
i dont know what i start with

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be surrounded by `$` signs.  For example, `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$.

Comment: This is a _separable_ equation...

Comment: oh...yes right SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{ydy}{xdx}= \frac{\sqrt{1+y^2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\leadsto \\
\frac{d(1+y^2)}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}= \frac{d(1+x^2)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \leadsto \\   \sqrt{1+y^2}=c+ \sqrt{1+x^2}.
$$

Comment: Certainly these photon emissions make it a brilliant calculation.

Comment: I SOLVE THIS FOR YOUR HELP THANXXXXXXX